# Diagnosing Exception in Finalizer thread

Tags: .net, exception, finalizer

I have an application with a rare crash in the field.  In most circumstances, these crashes produce an exception log with a stack trace, as I register for all the standard unhandled exception event handlers (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` and `DispatcherUnhandledException`).  However, this particular crash does not produce an exception log, which leads me to suspect that a misbehaving third-party component (containing unmanaged code) is causing an exception in the Finalizer thread.

Is there some way I can prove that this is, indeed, what is happening?  It's unfortunately not reproducible (my suspicion is a timing/threading issue), so ideally there is some way to log the diagnostic information at runtime, rather than while attached via the debugger.

Comment: If the unmanaged code is causing an Access Violation, then there should be evidence for this, i.e. the UnhandledException handler would log out this fact.  Have you checked the event logs of the misbehaving systems?  Perhaps there is some crash info.  It's also possible that the CLR itself has crashed, so nothing to do at the point other than kill the process, and no logging of course.

Comment: I have seen this using the Sybase ASE drivers for .NET... Just horrible... (probably caused by incorrect implementation of `IDisposable`). You can prevent the finalizer on the object if you know what it is. Do you know?

Comment: Did you check the event log? You may get some clue over there. I've done it earlier..

Comment: I unfortunately don't know which component it is; I'm suspecting third-party components only on the basis that I don't have any finalizers in my code and I'm not aware of any other way besides CLR destabilization or an exception in the Finalizer thread to cause a crash without tripping one of the logging events.

Comment: Exceptions from finalizer thread are visible thru `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event. Probably your logger library doesn't flush logs on every write?